# Enabling Remember me on CAS 3.4.2 with default implementation

Tags: single-sign-on, cas, remember-me

i have deployed my cas.war file.
Default login is working fine.

For enabling Remember me, i followed.
https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Remember+Me

but still when i do login selecting remember me option.
It simply logs me in without remembering.

So each time i have to enter username :test & password: test while accessing:
localhost:8080/cas/login

i want it to once allowed login to remember, so that for next hit on 
localhost:8080/cas/login identify me from cookies generated in remember me option

Any help from techno legends on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Where you are selecting remember me option, whenever you enter any username and password almost all browsers will ask Remember me option, if you are using the browser level option check the browser cache and auto-fill passwords are enabled or not (example- in Google chrome use ctrl+h),

If you are using CAS application level Remember-me, that behavior is different, when you use first time, in CAS data base your username and password along with you IP address will store, next time when you enter your username immediately from database your password will come.